# MS SQL Server 2012 exports datetime as script which it cannot import

Tags: sql-server, datetime, iso8601

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express. The database has a table [config] with a member of type 'datetime'. Exporting it (data only) by Management Studio as SQL script generates:

INSERT [dbo].[config] ([id], [name], [creation_date], ... ) VALUES (13, N'Test', CAST(N'2014-11-17 09:29:07.047' AS DateTime), ...)

Now when executing the generated script it complains that the value for the datetime type is invalid. I can manually fix it by replacing the blank between the date and the time by a "T":

INSERT [dbo].[config] ([id], [name], [creation_date], ... ) VALUES (13, N'Test', CAST(N'2014-11-17**T**09:29:07.047' AS DateTime), ...)

Looking into the docmentation of datetime, the format using a blank seems to be not supported.

How can I generate scripts with supported datetime format (i.e. incl. the 'T')?

How can I import the format that uses a blank without changing the imported script?

BTW, it looks like it works on other SQL Server installations, but I cannot find the difference. Also uninstalling and reinstalling SQL Server didn't help.

Comment: What types of datetime formatting are accepted is controlled by the Regional Settings in Windows on the server. Perhaps the other SQL Server installations (on other servers) have other Regional Settings.

Comment: This is now fixed in SQL Server 2014, but for SQL Server 2012 you will need the line Mikael suggests

Comment: Adam Marshall: i tested sql 2014 (v12) assemblies and it is not fixed in the Smo Scripter. The format is still bad there. It is weird that they only fixed it in management studio:-|

Answer (score 15):

> How can I import the format that uses a blank without changing the
>   imported script?

You have to change the import script but just a little. Specify [dateformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) as `ymd` at the beginning of the script.

```
set dateformat ymd;
```

> How can I generate scripts with supported datetime format (i.e. incl.
>   the 'T')?

Vote for a change...

["Generate scripts" for data, scripts datetime in a locale dependent format](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1031765/ssms-generate-scripts-for-data-scripts-datetime-in-a-locale-dependent-format)

Comment: I cannot change the imported script since it is generated (by Management Studio). Hence my question was "How can I import ... **without changing** the imported script?". However, thanks for placing the ticket for this bug.

Comment: Why is that? It is just text and can be modified.

Comment: Its a batch process which runs in the background automatically. I will have to add some patching step to the batch which finds and fixes the affected insert statements in a bulk of scripts. Note that the single insert statement of my OP was just an example. Of this is possible, but it is also possible to use a different RDBM instead of MS SQL Server, a different operating system or no SQL at all- to say it a little bit provocative. Its only a matter costs :-)

Comment: You don't have to find the insert statements. Just add one line at the top of the script. Or in some other way make sure that the connection you are using to execute the scripts first has executed `set dateformat ymd;`.

Answer (score 1):

A dateformat instruction is all is takes. Once the **SET DATEFORMAT** is in place, I don't even need to use the **CAST AS**.

Also note that your date format depends on where you are in the world. Being in Denmark, mine are in the format DD-MM-YYYY and 24 hour clock, so my dateformat instruction would be **DMY** rather than **YMD**. If the sequence is wrong, you will probably get an error about value exceeding the permitted value. I did. :)

Here is an example of code that worked for me just now using Microsoft's own SQL editor:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
INSERT INTO mytable ([id],[page],[saved]) VALUES ('2','29','16-01-2017 13:53:22')
```

Happy coding, mate.